# How to Convert Upper case string to Camel Case and keeping the Acronyms as it is?

Tags: java, string, h2, camelcasing

I am working on **H2 DB** and trying to create a Java function to convert Uppercase Strings into Camelcase for my dataset. Although, I am relatively a newbie in JAVA, but after some research I was able to arrive at the solution below.

```
DROP ALIAS toCamelCase if exists;
CREATE ALIAS toCamelCase AS $$
String toCamelCase(String s)
{ 
   String[] parts = s.split("\\s+");
   String camelCaseString = "";
   for (String part : parts)
   {
      if(part != null && part.trim() != "")
      {
        camelCaseString = camelCaseString + part.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + part.substring(1).toLowerCase() + " ";
      }
   }
   return camelCaseString;
} $$;
```

Now this does solve 95 percent of my problem, but the issue is that there are some elements in the dataset which are acronyms or short forms, for eg: **F.T.E** or **TBB** which as a result of this code are being transformed into **F.t.e** or **Tbb**. Can I achieve the same result but this time keeping the acronyms or short forms in their original form for the strings of data I am working on?

Appreciate the help!

Comment: It's not possible without some dictionary of acronyms. Even then, it would be very difficult to identify a word that also happens to be an acronym.

Comment: I agree! I thought of creating a lookup of such Acronyms but that would have been a lot of manual work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent acronyms from being changed, create a separate .txt file with a list on *known* acronyms. Then you can prevent it from being changed by simply doing this:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        if (part == line)
            break;
        else
            camelCaseString = camelCaseString + part.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + part.substring(1).toLowerCase() + " ";
    }
}
```

Replace this to be the contents of the for each loop.

> Remember to set "file" to a File object that contains the .txt file.